# Как обновить JS ссылку на элемент?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как для JQ обновить ссылку на элемент при смене его места?

[hillula.glenview-locksmith.com/limonvilkaizelen](http://hillula.glenview-locksmith.com/limonvilkaizelen)

```
var blockA = $(".blockA");
var blockB = $(".blockB");
$(".blockA").remove();
$(".blockB").remove();
$(".cont").append(blockB);
$(".cont").append(blockA);
```

Поле этих манипуляций перестает работать блок:

> $(".LIME-blockRight").on("click", function() {;

Если я правильно понимаю, теряется ссылка на элемент. Как исправить?

Comment: Надо заново повесить обработчик после append

Comment: можно простой пример?

Comment: `$(".LIME-blockRight").on("click", function() {;` заново

Comment: Спасибо! Сделал так $("body").on("click", ".LIME-blockRight", function() { ... });

Answer (score 3):

Вместо `.remove()` используйте [`.detach()`](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) – это вынимает элемент из DOM, но сохраняет все его атрибуты.

```js
var blockA = $(".blockA")
  , blockB = $(".blockB")
  , out = $('#out');

blockA.on('click', _click);
blockB.on('click', _click);

function _click(e){ out.text('Нажали блок ' + $(e.currentTarget).text()); }

$('#btn-swap').on('click', function(){
  $("#cont").append($(".blockB").detach()); // <- Магия! Забираем блоки
  $("#cont").append($(".blockA").detach()); // вместе с привязанными слушателями событий!
});
```

```css
#top, #cont {border:1px solid #999;padding:20px;margin:5px 20px;}
.blockA, .blockB { width:40px; height:40px; display:inline-block;text-align:center;color:#FFF;cursor:pointer;margin-left:4px;}
.blockA {background-color:#F60;}
.blockB {background-color:#390;}
#out{ width:220px;height:30px;border:1px solid #CCC;position:fixed;right:50px;top:0;background-color:rgba(180,180,180,0.8);padding-top:5px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;text-align:center}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top">
  <div class="blockA">A</div>
  <div class="blockB">B</div>
</div>
<div id="cont"></div>
<button id="btn-swap">Перенести блоки вниз</button>
<div id="out">Нажмите какой-нибудь блок</div>
```

Comment: Ваш код будет прекрасно работать если убрать `.detach()`. Каждый DOM элемент имеет `parentNode` свойство. `.detach()` устанавливает его в `null` (используя `parentElem.removeChild(elem)`), а `.append` опять устанавливает его, но теперь указывая на уже другой элемент `$("#cont")[0]`. Так что можно сразу использовать `append`, чтобы перетащить элемент со всеми его потрахами на новое место на странице. В остальном - пример отличный и +1 от меня.

Comment: Согласен, в примере можно обойтись без `.detach()`. В реальной задаче, может быть, должно пройти какое-то время без этих элементов в DOM, и повторное их появление в новом месте позже. Тогда понадобится их как-то сохранить – в переменную, с помощью `detach()`.

Answer (score -1):

Сделал так: `$("body").on("click", ".LIME-blockRight", function() { ... });`